# Creating detail view content programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, view, uisplitviewcontroller

I am making an app which uses a splitviewcontroller and will have over 100 different pieces of content. I want to make it so when I select a row, the content changes dynamically. Before, I was creating 100 nib files and separate view controllers before realizing the inefficiency.

I want different labels shown in the detail view when I select a row.

As a guide, I am using the MultipleDetailViews sample code provided by apple.

Also, if anyone can help me out with how to have a button for back and forward (changing table view content) that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are the same just different labelled views, then you could create a single nib file with a view that has all the common elements and then perhaps, create a small template view in the nib which is not contained in the main view and is hidden by default, every time you switch to a new page you can the use you can then use you template view to build the fields for you page. You could also have a few different template views for the different kinds of fields you want to display. To store all this information to drive all of this, you can create simple property list files for each page which contain information like the field title, order, my type or width. Getting the path to a property list file from you app package is easy with methods like [[NSBundle mainBundle] patterForResourceOfName:extension:];, Using properties list can make it easy to change you app, it is even possible to add features like uploading of new nibs without having to resubmit you app to apple, just do a periodic search for new property list files from some server, parsing PropertyList files is really easer too, NSDictionary and NSArray all serialise them selves as property list.